# How to test user belongs to a list of group using Chef Inspec?

Tags: inspec

I have a user `bogus_user` that belongs to three groups `bogus_user, sftpusers and airflow`.

In my spec I have the following declaration but I have to put the groups in a particular order for it to pass validation. I dont think this ideal, is there a way to have it check the list of groups and not care about the order?

```
describe user('bogus_user') do
  it { should exist }
  its('uid') { should eq 1002 }
  its('groups') { should include [ 'bogus_user', 'sftpusers', 'airflow' ] }
  its('home') { should eq '/var/ftp/pub/bogus_user' }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the nicest nor ideal solution, but it works:

```
describe user('bogus_user') do
  it { should exist }
  its('uid') { should eq 1002 }
  %w(bogus_user sftpusers airflow).each do |group|
    its('groups') { should include group }
  end
  its('home') { should eq '/var/ftp/pub/bogus_user' }
end
```